# Android Studio CountDownTimer Navigation

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to develop an application where on one layout, there would only be a start button and upon hitting the start button, it would navigate to another layout where the countdowntimer would start running automatically. I am able to implement the countdowntimer but when i try to navigate to another activity after pressing the start button, the application crashed. Please tell me if there is an approach to do it. Thanks

The code for Layout 1: Only with start button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="action1" />
```

The code for Layout 2:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
```

Lastly this is the Java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonStart;
TextView textCounter;

MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_countdown);

    buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    textCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  myCountDownTimer =  new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 1000);
  myCountDownTimer.start();
        }});

}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textCounter.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " seconds remaining : ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        textCounter.setText("Finished");

    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void action1(View View){setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}
```

These are the errors that i received in logcat

```
--------- beginning of crash
10-09 03:36:02.651    2183-2183/com.fluke.kgwee.flukegame E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fluke.kgwee.flukegame, PID: 2183
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.fluke.kgwee.flukegame.MainActivity$MyCountDownTimer.onTick(MainActivity.java:46)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:133)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Post your code and stack trace.

Comment: Done. Let me know if you have any idea what went wrong.

Comment: Hi there, appreciate your help. I tested the codes but still, the application is crashing after the start button.

Comment: Logcat: Process: com.fluke.kgwee.flukegame, PID: 2334
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.fluke.kgwee.flukegame.MainActivity$MyCountDownTimer.onTick(MainActivity.java:48)

Comment: at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:133)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code: 
The code for Layout 1: activity_main.xml , Only with start button

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Start" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code for Layout 2: count_down_activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java file: MainActivity.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Context mContext;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              mContext = this;
              Button startBrowser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
              startBrowser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View view) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(mContext, CountDownActivity.class));
                 }
              });
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
              // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action 
              // bar if it is present.
              getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
              return true;
       }

}
```

Java File 2: CountDownActivity.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CountDownActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textCounter;
    MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.count_down_activity);

              textCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);

              myCountDownTimer =  new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 1000, textCounter);
              myCountDownTimer.start();

       }
       public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

            private TextView textCounter;
            public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, TextView textCounter) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
                this.textCounter = textCounter;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                this.textCounter.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000l + " seconds remaining : ");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                this.textCounter.setText("Finished");

            }

        }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action 
          // bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          return true;
       }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidsample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidsample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidsample.CountDownActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you try my code ? I sure it's working well. Your problem is you don't pass an instance of TextView into  MyCountDownTimer  class.

Comment: The application is able to run, but upon hitting the start button, the application just crashes.

Comment: I has already tried test it. Don't have any problem when i hitting the start button, CountDownTimer working well and update to TextView. Make sure using my code  myCountDownTimer =  new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 1000, textCounter);

Comment: How is it possible. I opened a new project copied all the codes and tried running the emulators. But still, the application crashes.

Comment: I revalidated the program and cleaned project. Now it says that I have a problem along this line                                     this.textCounter.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000l + " seconds remaining : ");

Comment: Put the Button and TextView in the same xml file.

Comment: On the same layout, it will work. However, my idea is that when you press start it will bring you to another activity where the timer starts to run. Any idea how to go about doing it?

Comment: Hey Ve Pham, how do i modify the codes if I want it to navigate to another activity upon countdowntimer finishes counting.

Comment: It look like this:       @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                this.textCounter.setText("Finished");
    startActivity(new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class));
            }

Comment: I tried adding it into the Java File 2, however it does not recognise mContext. Any advise?

Comment: You need to add context, look like this: public class CountDownActivity extends Activity {
 private Context mContext;
    ....
  @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.count_down_activity);
     mContext = this;
     .....

Comment: Alright understood. Able to get it working ! Thanks alot